# Convert a string into a time interval (?)

Tags: qlikview

I am loading in strings that represent time frames with the format `DD days, HH:MM:SS`, and I want to create a graph in which these time frames are the expression. That means that I need to convert them into some number-like format. `Interval()` doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? Should I reformat the string prior to loading to something other than `DD days, HH:MM:SS` so that it is more easily usable?

Comment: I don't understand that format? For example how would the time from 2015/05/05 14:00 to 2015/05/06 16:00 display? Once I understand that we can do it with some string manipulation and various multiplications of the pieces to get it all back to a number QlikView will understand

Comment: That would be displayed as "1 day, 2:00:00"

Comment: Would be simple in QlikView itself: 
=interval(interval#(replace('1 days 02:00:00', ' days ', '.'),'D.h:mm:ss'),'DD.hh:mm:ss')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could go about solving this. Your idea of reformatting prior to loading sounds like a good option, since QlikView doesn't support regular expressions.

I think the best way to solve your problem is to write a simple Python script that replaces the spaces, comma, and letters with a colon. Then, you'll have a much more workable string in `DD:HH:MM:SS` format. Of course, this assumes you have a flat file that you can easily tweak:

```
import re
myreg = re.compile('(\s(day|days),\s)')    ## we'll look for " day, " and " days, "
newfilestr = ""
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        newfilestr += re.sub(myreg, ':', line)
outputf = open('fixedtimeformat.txt', 'w')
outputf.write(newfilestr)
outputf.close()
```

Comment: These values are coming from a Python script anyway, so this will work well. Thanks!